# Why the data of my form not adding to my database in flask-sqlalchemy and jinja template?

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, jinja2

I have a function that when you click the button it shows a form then it will add a card containing the data of the submitted form.

routes.py :

```
@app.route("/user", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def user():
    form = BudgetForm()
    budgets = Budgets.query.all()
    return render_template("user.html", title=current_user.username, form=form, budgets=budgets)

@app.route("/add_budgets", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def add_budgets():
    form = BudgetForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        budget = Budgets(budget=form.budget.data)
        db.session.add(budget)
        db.session.commit()
        return redirect(url_for('user'))
    return render_template("user.html", form=form)
```

forms.py:

```
class BudgetForm(FlaskForm):
    budget = IntegerField('Budget', validators=[DataRequired(), NumberRange(min=100, max=1000000)])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')
```

models.py:

```
class Budgets(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    budget = db.Column(db.Integer, nullable=False)
    date_posted = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.utcnow)
    budget_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id'), nullable=False)
    expense = db.relationship('Expenses', backref='budget_expenses', lazy=True)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Budgets('{self.budget}')"
```

user.html :

```
<div class="dash-cards">
                {% for budget in budgets %}
                    <div class="card-single"> 
                        <div class="card-body"> 
                            <span class="fas fa-coins"></span> 
                            <div> 
                                <h5>{{ budget.date_posted.strftime('%Y-%m-%d') }}</h5> 
                                <h4>{{ budget.budget}}</h4>
                            </div> 
                        </div> 
                        <div class="card-footer"> 
                            <a href="">Add Expenses</a> 
                        </div> 
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
            </div>

            <div class="popup">
                <div class="popup-content">
                    <form action="{{ url_for('add_budgets') }}" method="POST">

                        <div>
                            {{ form.budget.label(class="form-control-label", id="txt") }}
                            {{ form.budget(class="form-control") }}
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            {{ form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info" )}}
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
    </div>
```

I also query in the command line but nothing shows up. There is no error when submitting form.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should refactor your add_budgets() function to look more like this:

```py
def add_budgets():
    form = BudgetForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            budget = Budgets(budget=form.budget.data)
            if budget:
                db.session.add(budget)
                db.session.commit()
                return redirect(url_for('user'))
            else:
                # budget didn't get created
                print("budget is {}".format(budget))
                return render_template("user.html", form=form)
    else:
        return render_template("user.html", form=form)
```

My suspicion without trying the code is that your budget object is not getting created `budget = Budgets(budget=form.budget.data)`. I hope this helps you figure it out.